# How can you run an iex session and a phoenix server attached to the same database and mix environment in production?

Tags: phoenix-framework, elixir-mix, elixir, elixir-iex

When you run a server like `MIX_ENV=prod mix phx.server` and then on another screen attached to the same server try to run a mix-environment attached iex session like `iex -S mix` then you get an error and shutdown with a complaint like `Failed to start Ranch listener VukWeb.Endpoint.HTTP in :ranch_tcp:listen([port: 4000]) for reason :eaddrinuse (address already in use)`

Is there a way to run an iex session while a server is running in a separate screen attached to the same database? I'm confused as to why `iex -S mix` is even trying to connect to an external port, as that iex session should have no server running nor require an external port simply for loading the mix environment?

I'm aware you can run the server with an iex session like `MIX_ENV=prod iex -S mix phx.server`, but my understanding is that is neither ideal for performance nor is it nice to have your iex session interrupted by streams of user logs as requests are processed (which is what we're doing right now). I also tried switching up the port like `MIX_ENV=prod PORT=4040 iex -S mix` but the flag seems to go ignored, as the complaint comes back the same with a reference to port 4000. I'm wonder if maybe there's some hardcoding that's causing the environment variable to be ignored, and if just undoing this hardcoding and switching it to a different port like this is the right approach, even if the port goes unused by the non-server mix environment.

If anyone has a tip on how you can get both a iex session and serving running—or has a different suggestion for workflow that makes such a desire unnecessary—would love to hear!

Thanks

Comment: How is your config file loading the `port` option? Can you check if your prod.exs has something like `http: [port: {:system, "PORT"}],`?

Comment: There's a hardcoding of port 4000 for htttp / 443 for https. Is the suggestion then to run the two environments on different ports that I pass with a PORT= flag when run? Or is there syntax to pass a fallback in the config in case of nothing getting passed?

Comment: You can try `port: System.get_env("PORT") || 4000`. Are your using `--remsh` to connect to the running server?

Comment: Another developer's deploying so can't check right now, but I think that should work, thanks. Not using --remsh, just ssh'ed directly in so running locally from the server.

Comment: Yep, also had to switch out the port for HTTPS, but now it works! Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

[`Mix`](https://hexdocs.pm/mix) has a perfect very detailed documentation.

[`Mix.Tasks.Run`](https://hexdocs.pm/mix/Mix.Tasks.Run.html#content) is a default task. `iex -S -mix` is essentially equivalent to `iex -S mix run`.

The latter starts your application, which [wild reasonable guess] in turn starts `cowboy` as a dependency. Hence the error.

```
 iex -S mix run --no-start
```

is what you are looking for. This task accepts several arguments, other are listed on the help page I linked.

Comment: Thanks, this is great for getting an iex session running—but unfortunately I guess without running the dependencies you don't get the application environment loaded and so get errors like `repo App.Repo is not started, please ensure it is part of your supervision tree` when trying to use Repo, for example.

Comment: Of course, you have to start needed applications manually. If your goal is to start everything save for `cowboy`, you might create new `mix` environment and start the dependent / included applications based on the environment.

Comment: That seems like a good solution, thanks. To ensure the environment is the same (including impacts of cowboy) and for something quick it seems like just undoing the hardcoding and setting different ports based on an environment flag works.